# Segmentation fault while trying to print size of a vector inside a structure

Tags: c++

This piece of code gives me an error

```
struct state{
    int time_taken;
    vector<int>time_live;
    string loc_name;
    vector<int>loc;
};


for(int u=0;u<(A[start].loc.size());u++)
{
  l=A[start].loc[1];
  if(A[l].time_taken < min_time)
  { 
    min_time=A[l].time_taken;
    finish = l;
  }
}
```

This gives a segmentational fault .

Comment: At what line does it seg-fault? Have you checked that your indices are valid?

Comment: This lacks the most important pieces of information. What's `A`? What's `start`? Boil your problem down to a minimal self-contained example that exhibits the problem. Usually you'll find the problem that way. If you don't, you have a perfect repro to come back here with and ask us. And you might want to learn to use the debugger.

Comment: Also, make sure you're posting the code that's failing.  This looks suspect in that it's not actually using the loop control variable anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if `A[start]` is out of range then you may get a problem, which may or may not be a seg fault, depending on what `A` is.

Secondly, in the loop you have `A[start].loc[1]`, which will be out of range if `A[start].loc` is empty. Did you mean `loc[u]`?

Answer (score 0):

As from the above code.

before for loop make sure

```
start < A.size();
```

Inside for loop

```
l = A[start].loc[u];  // instead of 1
```

and before

```
if(A[l].time_taken < min_time) 
check
if (l < A.size())
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Anthony Williams's first point, but my guess is that `A[l]` is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to access A by using A.at(start) if this is out of range it will now throw an exception as opposed to segfaulting